# Lee-Parker Yamabe problem proposition 4.6

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, geometric-analysis

I believe there may be a gap towards the end of the proof of proposition 4.6 in the Bulletin of the AMS paper *The Yamabe Problem* by Lee and Parker : https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-17/issue-1/The-Yamabe-problem/bams/1183553962.full. They are trying to produce a minimizer to the Yamabe quotient on the standard round sphere. They proceed by considering the corresponding sub-critical problem for which it is standard to produce a smooth minimizer. This produces a family $\{\varphi_{s}\}$, which (since we are on the sphere), may not stay uniformly bounded as $s \to p= \frac{2n}{n-2}. $ They proceed by renormalizing the sequence using a family of chosen conformal diffeomorphisms, and establish that this renormalized sequence converges weakly in $ W^{1,2} $ and $C^2_{loc}(S^n)\setminus\{P\} $ (P denotes the north pole) to a function $\psi$, which they want to show is a minimizer. However towards the end of page 56, they claim that $$ \|\psi_{s}\|_{p}^p \geq Vol(S^n)^{1-\frac{s}{p}}\|\varphi_{s}\|_{s}^p ,$$ implies $ \|\psi\|_{p} \geq 1.$ It is this claim which I have problems with. The control they have on $\psi_{s}$ near the north pole is not enough to rule out the mass "escaping out to the infinity". Indeed one can consider a family of Aubin-Talenti bubbles on the sphere which would show this claim cannot be true, unless they are using something else about $\psi_{s}$ I'm not seeing. Hope someone can clarify this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting that, as part of the renormalization, the functions $\psi_s$ all satisfy $\psi_s(-P)=1$ (here $-P$ is the south pole).  In particular, since $\psi$ is $C^2$ away from the north pole, $\lVert \psi \rVert_p > 0$.  You can get $\lVert \psi \rVert_p^p \geq 1$ using the Brezis-Lieb lemma:

$$ \lVert \psi \rVert_p^p = \lim_{s \to p} \left( \lVert \psi_s \rVert_p^p - \lVert \psi - \psi_s \rVert_p^p \right) . $$

Set $u_s := \psi_s - \psi$.  By the Brezis-Lieb lemma, the normalization of $\psi_s$, and the fact $\lVert \psi \rVert_p \in (0,1]$,

$$ \tag{$\ast$}\label{bl}\lim_{s \to p} \lVert u_s \rVert_p^p = \lim_{s \to p} \lVert \psi_s \rVert_p^p - \lVert \psi \rVert_p^p \geq 1 - \lVert \psi \rVert_p^2 . $$

Now recall that, by construction, $u_s \rightharpoonup 0$ in $W^{1,2}$.  Then $u_s \to 0$ in $L^2$.  Therefore

\begin{align*}
 \lim_{s \to p} \Lambda\lVert u_s \rVert_p^2 & \leq \lim_{s \to p} \int_{S^n} (\psi - \psi_s)\Box (\psi - \psi_s) && \text{(defn $\Lambda$)} \\
 & = \lim_{s \to p} \int_{S^n} \left( -\psi\Box\psi + 2\psi\Box(\psi-\psi_s) + \psi_s\Box\psi_s \right) && \text{(expand)} \\
 & = -\int_{S^n} \psi\Box\psi + \lim_{s \to p} \int_{S^n} \psi_s \Box \psi_s && \text{(weak convergence)} \\
 & \leq -\Lambda\lVert\psi\rVert_p^2 + \Lambda && \text{(defn $\Lambda$ and $\psi_s$)} .
\end{align*}

Combining this with \eqref{bl} yields $\lVert\psi\rVert_p^2 \leq \lVert\psi\rVert_p^p$.  Since $\lVert \psi \rVert_p > 0$, we conclude that $\lVert\psi\rVert_p \geq 1$.

Comment: So to just to clarify, do you mean to say the authors meant to write "we may assume the sup of \varphi_{s} is attained at the north pole" instead of the south pole as written? Because otherwise I'm not seeing how \psi_{s} are bounded from above by 1. The function t_{\alpha} is largest at the north pole whereas in the paper the \varphi_{s} are largest at the south pole.

Comment: @Marc You are right; I misread what they meant by $P$.  The key point is anyway that $\psi$ isn’t zero at the south pole (as it would be for the bubbles you are worried about).  I’ve modified accordingly, and hopefully not made any more mistakes guessing at their notation.

Comment: Ah okay, very nice!